# Symbolic link or Junction to a Networked Samba Share

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, samba, symbolic-link

I have a samba share mounted as a network drive. However, I can't make any sort of symbolic link or junction point to it. Is this possible?

When I try the following command:

```
mklink /D X:\Samba\dir C:\path_to_dir
```

I get "The file or directory is not a reparse point."

```
mklink /J X:\Samba\dir C:\path_to_dir
```

I get "Local NTFS volumes are required to complete this operation."

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there possibly one drive that is FAT32 ?

Answer (score 7):

It works like this

```
mklink /d "C:\path_to_dir" "X:\Samba\dir"
```

Comment: I used `mklink /d path_to_dir X:\Samba\dir` but it doesn't work, but providing the absolute path `mklink /d C:\path_to_dir X:\Samba\dir` does work